# generate a list of string elements without the quotation mark

Tags: python, list, replace, single-quotes

I would like to generate a list of string elements, but without the quotation marks. This is how I am generating the list:

```
  [f'test_{i+1}' for i in range(5)]
```

This yields the following result:

```
['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3', 'test_4', 'test_5']
```

How do I remove the quotaton marks? I tried as shown below but this gives me a syntax error.

```
   [f'test_{i+1}' for i in range(5)].replace(''', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot have quotes in the print statement, you can use

```
print(', '.join(['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3', 'test_4', 'test_5']))
```

Note that this is joining all of the elements together into a single string.

Comment: The `join` method is located under the docs on [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). When you normally print the list, the commas are the separators between distinct elements. The join method joins these distinct string elements with the preceding string (in this case, I've used `', '`).

Answer (score 3):

There are no quotation marks in your strings. The quotation marks you trying to remove are a part of the Python syntax. They are necessary to delimit your strings. You cannot remove them.

P.S: Python lists have no `replace` method. If you want to replace anything within the string, the following syntax will do:

```
a = # the character to be replaced
b = # the character to replace a
[f'test_{i+1}'.replace(a, b) for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `Python lists have no replace method`. Yes they don't, but you can replace items at any already existing index.

Comment: Of course, you can. But that is not what OP is doing in their question. @deponovo